# Wie nennt man die Dinge, die sich in Kleidungsstücke befinden und die Größe zeigen und auch manchmal die Pflegeanweisungen?

Tags: single-word-request

[image: Clothing Tags]

Könnte man »Etiketten« sagen?  Auf Englisch heißen sie »tags.«

Comment: Es gibt sogar ein ganzes Gesetz dazu (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Textilkennzeichnungsgesetz), der Name scheint aber nicht einheitlich zu sein. Entweder *Pflegeetikett* oder einfach *Textiletikett*.

Comment: Oder vielleicht auch _Textillabel_

Comment: In manchen Kleidungsstücken ist das ja fast schon ein mehrseitiges Buch, das da eingenäht ist. Das würde ich dann nicht mehr ein *Etikett* oder *Label* nennen.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich und mit bekanntem Kontext kann man sagen: „Zieh dich mal ordentlich an, dein Schild guckt raus.“ Spontan hatte ich noch an _Waschzettel_ gedacht.

Comment: Ich nenne diese Dinger *Hinten,* weil ihr Hauptzweck für mich ist, zu markieren, wo bei einem Kleidungsstück hinten ist. (Es gibt keine Kleidungsstücke, bei denen diese Dinger vorne sind; es gibt nur Kleidungsstücke, die falschrum am Hinten angebracht sind.)

Comment: @Hubert Schölnast: ... sondern _Abreißkalender_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ja, am verbreitetsten ist wohl schlicht *Etiketten*.

Auch schon gehört: **Pflegefähnchen** und entsprechend für die Abbildungen **Größenfähnchen** und zusammenfassend, generisch folglich, **Textilfähnchen** (von *Fähnchen*, der Verkleinerungsform für *Fahne*).

Entsprechende Bildungen mit *Schildchen* gehen auch.

Das in den Kommentaren genannte *Label* wird bevorzugt für den Herstellernamen verwendet.

Answer (score 2):

Offenbar gibt es hier regionale Unterschiede. Ich kann diese Frage daher nur für meine Region beantworten (Osten Österreichs):

- **Etikett**
  Das ist nur jener Teil, auf dem der Markenname und die Größenangabe stehen.
  Bei Hemden und T-Shirts findet man das Etikett meist oben, in der Mitte des Kragens.
- **Waschanleitung, Pflegeanleitung, Waschzettel**
  Das ist jener Teil, auf dem steht, wie das Kleidungsstück zu waschen oder zu putzen ist. Dieser Teil besteht oft auch aus mehreren Blättern (manchmal sogar mehr als 10 Blätter).
  Bei Hemden und T-Shirts findet man die Waschanleitung meist an der linken Seitennaht, im unteren Bereich.
- **Fähnchen** (Pflegefähnchen, Größenfähnchen, Textilfähnchen usw.)
  zumindest in Österreich völlig ungebräuchlich

Einen gemeinsamen Namen für Etikett und Waschanleitung kenne ich nicht.